# Difference between foo=list, foo=[], and foo=list()?

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python (but not programming in general) and don't really understand what is going on with lists. I have thousands of test sets in a text file and each test set is 256 (could be dfferent) x,y points. What I want to do is store each point in a test set to a list and then store each list in another list, effectively creating a 2D list. Two of the three options I've tried are error free but I don't know what the different options mean or why I should pick one over another.
This is not the same as ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) because that doesn't explain which of these is a list and what the other definitions are.

```
foo= list
foo.append(1)#TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int'

bar= []
bar.append(1)#no error

baz= list()
baz.append(1)#no error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one sets `foo` to the object `list`.  This is *not* an empty list, as you've discovered.  The object `list` is a built-in type ... and you now have an in-scope alias to the type.  You cannot append to a type; hence the error message.

The other two are classic ways to initialize a variable to an empty list.  The middle one uses list literal notation to construct a list, while the last one invokes the `list` type object as a function to generate an instance of the type.

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing `foo = list`, you're actually assigning `foo` to a built-in python object of list. `bar = list()` and `baz = []` both initiates two new variables as new vacant list. However in python `var_ = []` assigning is a bit faster compared to `var_ = list()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `foo = list` makes `foo` an alias for the `list` type. No actual `list` object has been instantiated in that line. However, if you have a `list` object, you **can** use `list.append()` (or `foo.append()`) in order to append to it.

Like so:

```
foo = list
bar = [1]

list.append(bar, 2)
# bar is now [1, 2]

foo.append(bar, 3)
# bar is now [1, 2, 3]
```

Since your example code calls `foo.append()` with only one argument (an int), the exception complains that it needs a `list` and not an `int`.

*Note:* This is not a special feature of the list class. All instance methods can be called in both forms: `some_object.func(a, b, c)` or `SomeType.func(some_object, a, b, c)`